# Spring MVC 3 bind a dynamically loaded field to a bean without using form:input tag?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have this webpage where i have used `form:input` as follows

```
</spring:bind> <spring:bind path="questionBeanPV.questions[148].questionDependency">
                <form:hidden path="${status.expression}" id="quesDep148" />
```

Here `questionBeanPV.questions[148]` is a Map of  so i have binded the object of  '148'th key to the field.

All is good till now.

But now i have to dynamically populate few more fields on the webpage using `jQuery-Ajax`.

How can i bind them ? Is it achievable ?

So that i do not have to do `request.getParameter("DynamicallyLoadedFields")`
?

Comment: You have to set the name to the form bean model attribute name, followed by a '.', followed by the rest of the path you would have done in the `form:input` tag.  Something like: `myModelAttr.mySubBean.myProperty'.  Spring MVC uses the name to identify how to bind the form request to the corresponding bean in your handler.

Comment: Are you saying the "few more fields" are populated by jQuery-Ajax or submit the dynamically populated "few more fields" using jQuery-Ajax?

Comment: few more fields are created using jQuery-Ajax

Comment: @CodeChimp will something like questionBeanPV.coAppQuestions[271].answer here coAppQuestions is a map and answer is a property of bean which is value of of 271th key

Comment: Yes, in your example, coAppQuestions would be either a `Map` keyed by some integer or even a `List` of some bean that has a property called `answer`.  `Map`s can be keyed off non-numerics as well, for instance a `String`.  One caveat: Spring MVC does not handle collections of collections very well at all, and it's a pain to deal with dynamic forms where you have to remove stuff from a collection.  If all you are doing is displaying stuff, then your fine, but as soon as you have to start adding things with nested `Collection`s then you have trouble.